# Updating a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset

I'm trying to update a DataTable that is part of a DataSet. I search through the table using a DataRow then pass the value into a DataRow for updating to the DataSet, however this is not working, can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

```
foreach(DataRow drHierarchyTrueValueList in ds.Tables["HierarchyTypeValueList"].Rows)
{
  foreach(DataRow drHierarchyListToUpdate in ds.Tables["Hierarchy"].Rows)
  {
    if (drHierarchyListToUpdate["HierarchyParent"] == 
        drHierarchyTrueValueList["HierarchyValueDescription"] && 
        Convert.ToInt32(drHierarchyListToUpdate["HierarchyParentType"]) != 0)
      {
         drHierarchyListToUpdate["HierarchyParentValue"] = 
             Convert.ToInt32(drHierarchyTrueValueList["HierarchyTrueValue"]);
      }
  }
  ds.Tables["Hierarchy"].AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?

Comment: The table doesn't update - when I bind it to aanother GridView the column "HierarchyParentValue" stays the same.

Comment: Does the line that should do the change get hit?

Comment: What type is `drHierarchyListToUpdate["HierarchyParent"]`? Does it work if you use `.Equals(...)`? Have you used the debugger to ensure that the code in the `if` is executed at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to this, and it worked:

```
foreach(DataRow drHierarchyListToUpdate in ds.Tables["Hierarchy"].Rows)
        {
            string HierarchyParent = drHierarchyListToUpdate["HierarchyParent"].ToString();
            string HierarchyValueDescription = drHierarchyTrueValueList["HierarchyValueDescription"].ToString();
            int HierarchyParentType = Convert.ToInt32(drHierarchyListToUpdate["HierarchyParentType"]);

            if (HierarchyParent == HierarchyValueDescription && HierarchyParentType != 0)
            {
                drHierarchyListToUpdate["HierarchyParentValue"] = Convert.ToInt32(drHierarchyTrueValueList["HierarchyTrueValue"]);
            }
            else if (HierarchyParent != HierarchyValueDescription && HierarchyParentType == 0)
            {
                drHierarchyListToUpdate["HierarchyParentValue"] = 0;
            }
        }
        ds.Tables["Hierarchy"].AcceptChanges();
```